# Is an enum constant-specific class body static or non-static?

Tags: java, enums, static, anonymous-inner-class

I have a enum type class:

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS() {
        @Override
        double apply(double x, double y) {       
            // ERROR: Cannot make a static reference
            // to the non-static method printMe()...
            printMe(x);
            return x + y;
        }
    };

    private void printMe(double val) {
        System.out.println("val = " + val);
    }

    abstract double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

As you see above, I have defined one `enum` type which has value `PLUS`. It contains a constant-specific body. In its body, I tried to call  `printMe(val);`, but I got the compilation error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method printMe().

Why do I get this error? I mean I am overriding an abstract method in `PLUS` body. Why is it in `static` scope? How to get rid of it?

I know adding a `static` keyword on `printMe(){...}` solves the problem, but I am interested to know if there is another way if I want to keep `printMe()` non-static?

---

Another issue, quite similar as above one, but this time the error message sounds the other way around, i.e. `PLUS(){...}` has non-static context:

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS() {
        // ERROR: the field "name" can not be declared static
        // in a non-static inner type.
        protected static String name = "someone";

        @Override
        double apply(double x, double y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    };

    abstract double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

I try to declare a `PLUS`-specific `static` variable, but I end up with error:

> the field "name" can not be declared static in a non-static inner type.

Why can I not define static constant inside `PLUS` if `PLUS` is an anonymous class? The two error messages sound contradictory to each other, as the 1st error message says `PLUS(){...}` has **static** context while the 2nd error message says `PLUS(){...}` has **non-static** context. I am even more confused now.

Comment: My question is why I get this error & is there a way to solve it but keep printMe() non-static

Comment: make `printMe()` protected and call `this.printMe(val)` inside `apply()`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, yes, change to protected makes it working. But again, my quenstion is why I get this error, & please also explain why change to protected makes it working?  Please make an answer, which I can accept. The point is to understand the reason than just make it work. Thanks.

Comment: The `printMe` method is private in your enum, every one of your enumerations is an implementation of the enum class, so they don't have access to the private method in their parent class. The puzzles me is the nature of the error.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo this is not surprising a all, an anonymous subclass of the `enum` will not see the field of its parent. The fix is to make `private void printMe(double val) {` be `protected`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Of course, but the wording of the message suggests something else, wrongly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well this is a strange case.

It appears that the problem is:

- In this case, the private member *should be accessible* ([6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1).):

  > Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.
- However, private members are not inherited ([8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)):

  > Members of a class that are declared `private` are not inherited by subclasses of that class.
- Therefore, `printMe` is not a member of the anonymous subclass and the compiler searches for it within the superclass* `Operation` ([15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)):

  > If there is an enclosing type declaration **of which that method is a member**, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.
  >
  > *This search policy is called the "comb rule". It effectively looks for methods in a nested class's superclass hierarchy before looking for methods in an enclosing class and its superclass hierarchy.*
- And here is where it gets strange. Because `printMe` is found in a class that *also encloses* `PLUS`, the object that the method is called on is instead determined to be an enclosing instance of `Operation`, which doesn't exist ([15.12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1)):

  > Otherwise, let T be the enclosing type declaration of which the method is a member, and let *n* be an integer such that T is the *n*'th lexically enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration immediately contains the method invocation. **The target reference is the *n*'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`.**
  >
  > **It is a compile-time error if the *n*'th lexically enclosing instance of `this` does not exist.**

So in short, because `printMe` is only a member of `Operation` (and not inherited), the compiler is compelled to invoke `printMe` *on a non-existent outer instance*.

However, the method is still accessible and we can find it by qualifying the invocation:

```
@Override
double apply(double x, double y) {
//  now the superclass is searched
//  but the target reference is definitely 'this'
//  vvvvvv
    super.printMe(x);
    return x + y;
}
```

---

> The two error messages sound contradictory to each other [...].

Yes, this is a confusing aspect of the language. On the one hand, an anonymous class is never static ([15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)), on the other hand, an anonymous class expression can *appear in a static context* and therefore has no enclosing instance ([8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).

> An anonymous class is always an inner class; it is never `static`.

> An instance of an inner class `I` whose declaration occurs in a static context has no lexically enclosing instances.

To help understand how this works, here is a formatted example:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Object() {
            int i;
            void m() {}
        };
    }
}
```

Everything in `italics` is the static context. The anonymous class derived from the expression in `bold` is considered inner and non-static (but has no enclosing instance of `Example`).

Since the anonymous class is non-static it cannot declare static non-constant members, despite that it is itself declared within a static context.

---

* Besides obscuring the matter a little, the fact that `Operation` is an enum is completely irrelevant ([8.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)):

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration that extends the immediately enclosing enum type. The class body is governed by the usual rules of anonymous classes [...].

Comment: This is definitely the best answer I have read so far on this. Very interesting.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think I have the answer about the nature of the error, but perhaps I can contribute a bit to the discussion.

When the Java compiler compiles your enum code, it produces a synthetic class that is somewhat as follows:

```
class Operation {

    protected abstract void foo();
    private void bar(){ }

    public static final Operation ONE;

    static {
        ONE = new Operation() {
            @Override
            protected void foo(){
                bar(); 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can verify the enum code looks somewhat like this by running javap in one of your enum classes.

This code above gives me the exact same error you're getting on your enum: "error: non-static method bar() cannot be referenced from a static context".

So here the compiler thinks you cannot invoke the `bar()` method, which is an instance method, from the static context in which the anonymous class is being defined.

It makes no sense to me, it should either be accesible or be denied access, but the error does not seem accurate. I am still puzzled, but this seems to be what is actually happening.

It would make more sense if the compilers said that that the anonymous class did not have access to `foo` since it is private on its parent class, but the compiler is firing this other error instead.

Comment: With your example, when you do `System.out.println(Operation.ONE.getClass());` the result is `class Operation$1` as you would expect. However, when you do the same thing with the enum version the result is simply `class Operation`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I get `Operation$1` as the class name when I do `System.out.println(Operation.ONE.getClass())` in both the enum version and the manually defined version I did above. Take into account that the anonymous class is not defined unless you actually have an abstract method in the enum.

Comment: I am using Java 8, but it makes not difference. This has not changed. For the sake of the argument I just tried in Java 7 and it is the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I'm being really dense. I was just doing `enum Operation { ONE }`.

Comment: In that case it makes sense, because no anonymous class would be defined for that matter. It can reuse the enum class itself, since the class is concrete. But when the enum class is abstract, it requires defining concrete classes out of it that implement the abstract methods. In those cases is when we see the anonymous class being defined in the synthetic code done by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, could you please check my **UPDATE** in my post ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The question following your update is easy to answer. Anonymous classes are never allowed static members.

As for your original question, the clearest way to understand what's going on is to try `this.printMe();` instead. Then the error message is much easier to understand, and gives the *real* reason `printMe();` doesn't work:

```
'printMe(double)' has private access in 'Operation'
```

The reason you can't use `printMe` is because it is `private` and the compile-time type of the `this` reference is an anonymous extension class of `Operation`, not `Operation` itself (see Edwin Dalorzo's answer). You get a different error message when you just write `printMe();` because for some reason the compiler doesn't even realise you're trying to call an instance method on `this`. It gives the error message that would make sense if you were trying to call `printMe` on no instance at all (i.e. as if it were a static method). The error message doesn't change if you make that explicit by writing `Operation.printMe();`.

Two ways to get around this are to make `printMe` protected, or to write

```
((Operation) this).printMe();
```

Answer (score 5):

`printMe` should not be `private` as you derive a new anonymous class with PLUS.

```
protected void printMe(double val) {
```

As to the nature of the error, enum/Enum, is a bit of an artifact; it eludes me at the moment: an inner class might access private things...

Comment: I think that's been established. The question is the weird nature of the error. Why the static-context error and not simply the classical message that the method does not exist or is not accessible?

Comment: Sorry added my response already to the answer. I guess a _private_ static method may be called, as does a normal _protected_ method. And the compiler gave a too narrow error.

Answer (score 4):

what is the type of `PLUS()`?
well this is basically type of `enum Operation`.

If you want to compare it to `java class`, its basically an `object` of the same class within itself.

now `enum Operation` has abstract method `apply` that means any of this type (namely operation) should implement this method . so far so good.

now the tricky part where you get the error.

as you see, `PLUS()` is basically a type of `Operation`. `Operation` has a `private` method `printMe()` meaning only `enum Operation` itself can see it not any other enum  including the sub-enums(just like the sub class and super class in java). also this method is not `static` either meaning you cannot call it unless u instantiate the class. so you are ended up with two options to solve the problem,

1. make the `printMe() method static` as compiler suggest
2. make the method `protected` so any `sub-enum`  `inherits` this methods  .

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, the reason making it static works is the automatic synthetic accessor functionality. You will still get the following compiler warning if it is private static.

> Access to enclosing method printMe(double) from the type Operation is
>   emulated by a synthetic accessor method

The only thing that doesn't work in this case is private non-static. All other security works, e.g. private static, protected non-static, etc. As someone else mentioned PLUS is an implementation of Operation, so private technically doesn't work, Java automatically does the favor of fixing it for you with the automatic synthetic accessor functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Making the printMe method static solves the compile error:

```
private static void printMe(long val) {
    System.out.println("val = " + val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one quite a bit, but I think the best way to understand it is to look at an analogous case that doesn't involve `enum`:

```
public class Outer {

    protected void protectedMethod() {
    }

    private void privateMethod() {
    }

    public class Inner {
        public void method1() {
            protectedMethod();   // legal
            privateMethod();     // legal
        }
    }

    public static class Nested {
        public void method2() {
            protectedMethod();  // illegal
            privateMethod();    // illegal
        }
    }

    public static class Nested2 extends Outer {
        public void method3() { 
            protectedMethod();  // legal
            privateMethod();    // illegal
        }
    }    
}
```

An object of class `Inner` is an inner class; each such object contains a hidden reference to an object of the enclosing `Outer` class.  That's why the calls to `protectedMethod` and `privateMethod` are legal.  They're called on the containing `Outer` object, i.e. `hiddenOuterObject.protectedMethod()` and `hiddenOuterObject.privateMethod()`.

An object of class `Nested` is a static nested class; there's no object of an `Outer` class associated with one.  That's why the calls to `protectedMethod` and `privateMethod` are illegal--there's no `Outer` object for them to work on.  The error message is `non-static method <method-name>() cannot be referenced from a static context`.  (Note that `privateMethod` is still visible at this point.  If `method2` had a different object `outer` of type `Outer`, it could call `outer.privateMethod()` legally.  But in the example code, there is no object for it to work on.)

An object of class `Nested2` is similarly a static nested class, but with a twist that it extends `Outer`.  Since protected members of `Outer` will be inherited, that makes it legal to call `protectedMethod()`; it will be operating on the object of class `Nested2`.  The private method `privateMethod()` isn't inherited, though.  So the compiler treats it the same as it does for `Nested`, which produces the same error.

The `enum` case is very similar to the `Nested2` case.  Each enum constant with a body causes a new anonymous subclass of `Operation` to be created, but it's in effect a static nested class (even though anonymous classes are usually inner classes).  The `PLUS` object does not have a hidden reference to an object of class `Operation`.  Thus, public and protected members, which are inherited, can be referenced and will operate on the `PLUS` object; but references to private members in `Operation` are not inherited, and they can't be accessed because there's no hidden object to work on.  The error message, `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method printMe()`, is pretty much the same as `non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`, just with the words in a different order.  (I'm not claiming that all the language rules are just like the `Nested2` case; but in this case, it's definitely helped me to see them as almost the same sort of construct.)

The same applies to references to protected and private *fields*.