# Why does this enum compile?

Tags: java, enums

I wanted to create an `enum` where each constant has a `Map` associated with it.  I accomplished this by giving each constant an instance initializer, like so:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum Derp {
    FOO {{
            mMap.put("bar", 1);
        }};

    // cannot be private
    protected final Map<String, Integer> mMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I found that if `mMap` is `private`, it cannot be referenced in the instance initializer.  The error is `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mMap`.  Before the reason for this occurred to me, I consulted [JLS §8.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2), which says in part:

> It is a compile-time error for the constructors, instance initializer blocks, or instance variable initializer expressions of an enum constant `e` to refer to `e` or to an enum constant of the same type that is declared to the right of `e`.

Aren't I breaking this rule by implicitly referencing `FOO` in `FOO`'s own instance intializer?  How does this compile?  It not only compiles, but works correctly at runtime.

(It occurred to me that `mMap` cannot be `private` because I'm implicitly creating an anonymous subclass which cannot reference a `private` field in its superclass.  Which is a bit weird in itself since enums are implicitly `final`...)

Comment: "enums are implicitly `final`" - [not quite](http://ideone.com/3bi0U1). Java needs to create implicit per-instance subclasses every time you do the thing with the braces next to an enum constant, so if you do that, the enum class isn't final. You still can't declare your own subclasses of it, though.

Comment: Qualify the call like `super.mMap.put(...);`. The reason behind this is just a weird specification.

Comment: @Radiodef I'm not convinced this is a duplicate.  I think this poster is asking two questions that were not asked in the linked-to post: (1) why is it legal if he uses `protected` and (2) why isn't the implicit self-reference illegal. I looked over the answers there, and they don't answer the question to my satisfaction.

Comment: @ajb That's exactly what prompted the question.  Not only does this compile, but it does not throw a NPE.  `FOO.mMap` contains the correct values at runtime.

Comment: sorry, I missed the part where you said it worked at runtime.

Comment: @ajb `protected` works because `protected` fields exist in the subclass, whereas the `private` fields don't (as taken from the other question).  As for why it works at runtime, the `.. mMap = new HashMap<>()` line is pre-pended to the `<init>` (constructor) code, so `mMap` is initialized before anything is ever put into it.

Comment: The specification referenced here just means you can't reference by name e.g. `enum Foo { FOO{{ System.out.println(FOO); }} }` because it's not initialized yet. It doesn't mean you can't access `this`. It's basically the same rule as any other initializer e.g. `int x = x;` or `static final Object o = new Object() {{ System.out.println(o); }};`.

Comment: @Radiodef In other words, you can reference `this` but not `Derp.FOO` because `Derp.FOO` has not been assigned yet.  Right?  I think that's the answer, if you want to make it one.

Comment: Question is closed so I can't answer but yes, that's right. `Derp.FOO` is null inside the initializer for `FOO`. http://ideone.com/SPf9zx I'll post an answer if it gets reopened, sorry.

Comment: I'd say the site is being ruined more by bad and careless questions, but unfortunately others who also don't like such questions can sometimes be too quick to close something as a duplicate.  This isn't the worst example--I've seen many worse cases of questions closed by good StackOverflow citizens who see a couple words and overreact.  Anyway, after doing a bunch of research, I've posted another answer over at the dupe question that might help clarify things (about the `private`/`protected`).  Finally, no matter how much of a problem you think this is, we don't allow foul language on SO.

Comment: Well, now that it's been reopened, the link is gone... here's where I put my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964926.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is a compile-time error for the constructors, instance initializer blocks, or instance variable initializer expressions of an enum constant `e` to refer to `e` or to an enum constant of the same type that is declared to the right of `e`.

The specification here just means you can't reference by *name* because the field referred to by `e` is not initialized yet. It doesn't mean you can't access `this`.

It's basically the same rule as any other initializer (like `int x = x;`).

We can see why with an example like ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/SPf9zx)):

```
enum Example {
    INSTANCE {{
        subversion();
    }};

    static void subversion() {
        System.out.println(INSTANCE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
null
INSTANCE
```

---

> I found that if `mMap` is private, it cannot be referenced in the instance initializer.

You can qualify the call as `super.mMap.put(...);`. The private `mMap` is not inherited, but it's accessible from the inner class. [I also covered this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971617/2891664). The short of it is that the simple name `mMap` refers to a non-existent outer instance of `Derp`.

We can verify this is the case with an example like ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/qjEXEl)):

```
class Example {
    private int x;

    class Inner extends Example {{
        x = 1;       // refers to the outer instance
        super.x = 2; // refers to the inner instance
    }}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example outer = new Example();
        Example inner = outer.new Inner();
        System.out.println(outer.x); // prints 1
        System.out.println(inner.x); // prints 2
    }
}
```

Except in your case `FOO` is static so there is no outer instance—hence compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `FOO` is it's own anonymous subclass of `Derp` - which already exists when `FOO` is created.

```
public class Enums {
    public enum Derp {
        FOO {{
            mMap.put("bar", 1);
        }};

        // cannot be private
        protected final Map<String, Integer> mMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Derp.class);
        System.out.println(Derp.FOO.getClass());
    }
}
```

> class Enums$Derp
>   class Enums$Derp$1