# Calling enum's method

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum:

```
 enum Days{
    TODAY{
        @Override
        public Date getLowerBound(){
            another();             //1
            currentUpperBound();   //2
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Date another() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    public abstract Date getLowerBound();

    public abstract Date another();

    private Date currentUpperBound(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why does `//2` causes compile-time error with

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method 
currentUpperBound() from the type Days
```

But `//1` compiles fine? Both methods are non-static. I can't see any problem... Maybe it has something to do with Eclipse?

***UPDATE:*** As @Florian Schaetz noticed in the comment, if we declare the method  having `static private` modifier it will work fine. Why?

Comment: the second is not abstract. This means that it must be `static` in the enum context.

Comment: private method cannot be override make currentUpperBound() to be public .

Comment: The error message is confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest making `currentUpperBounds()` **protected** instead of **private**. Another solution would be to prefix your call with `super.`, which also works:

```
@Override
public Date getLowerBound(){
   another();
   super.currentUpperBound();
   return null;
}
```

Alternatively, TODAY also works:

```
@Override
public Date getLowerBound(){
   another();
   TODAY.currentUpperBound();
   return null;
}
```

Mick Mnemonic mentioned the excellent answer in this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964926/is-an-enum-constant-specific-class-body-static-or-non-static), which explains it pretty nicely.

Comment: I understood the problem, yes. I'd make them having default access modifier. Tahnk you.

Comment: I am wondering why the error is totally unrelated. Though changing it to `protected` or `public` fixes it. Is it related to static context for some reason. **And changing the method to static fixes the error too...:O**

Comment: @Codebender Me too, but I presume that's eclipse all along.

Comment: Technically, defining the method as static also works. Seems that TODAY can access a static private, but not a non-static private. Interesting, will have to do some reading about that.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Indeed, interesting. Why does the static private method work?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

### Solution to your problem

I suggest making the `currentUpperBound()` method `protected`.

### Why?

You should consider **each value of your enum as an anonymous subclass of `Days`**. Moreover, since the enum must guarantee each of its value is unique (so that you can test equality with `==` for instance), **it is stored as a `static final` field** (hence also the habit of naming enum values with capital letters.

## Understanding the enum behind the scene

### Code equivalence

To show some code on how an enum works<sup>1</sup>:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    JESSE {
       @Override
       public void sayMyName() {
           System.out.println("Pinkman");
       }
    }, WALTER;

    public void sayMyName() {
        System.out.println("Heisenberg");
    }

    private void unreachableMethod() {
        // try again
    }
}
```

is (almost) equivalent to:

```
public class MyEnum {
    private static final MyEnum JESSE = new MyEnum() {
       @Override
       public void sayMyName() {
           System.out.println("Pinkman");
       }
    };
    private static final MyEnum WALTER = new MyEnum();

    public void sayMyName() {
        System.out.println("Heisenberg");
    }

    private void unreachableMethod() {
        // try again
    }
}
```

When you write it this way, some things become much easier to understand:

#### - why `==` works for testing enum equality

Only one pointer per value. `Object`'s `equals(Object)` is perfect here as it tests only that.

#### - why you can inherit methods from `MyEnum` or access `private static` ones, but not `private` non-static methods

- The values are stored as `static` fields so they cannot access instance context.
- The value inherit `MyEnum` so anything accessible through legacy is visible to them.

### Why did I say that is was *almost* equivalent?

There are some additional controls embedded within the enum mechanism.

For instance, the `switch` is able to tell whether you had a `case` for each value for an enum: try testing only some values and not defining a `default`, the compiler will raise a warning. This would be impossible if you were simply using an abstract class with constants.

The `values()` method also shows things are more evolved than my simple example, but I think this helps understanding.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> based on my understanding of the [JSL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)</sub>

Comment: But that doesn't provuide the reason for the static private.

Comment: The JSL says, that the enum body is a anonymous class, not a static one. But probably has to do something with that.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I thought of it while eating my lunch and think I understand a little better how it works behind the scene. I revamped my answer and would be interested in picking your brain about it.

Comment: @St.Antario I revamped my answer and think it answers all the questions now. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I found another funny detail: You CAN actually call the private non-static method. You only have to use `super.` . So in your example `super.unreachableMethod()` in the overriding `sayMyName`method works. And before the whole thing gets to easy... Prefixing it with `MyEnum.` also works. Funny, but slowly I realize how  fragmentary my understanding of Java is, especially with the details.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Nice catch! I did a quick try: this works with standard classes too. E.g. `class A { private static A a = new A() {/* override sth here */}; }`: the inner class can access the private methods of the parent with `super`. This obviously works only because the anonymous class is defined within the scope of its parent. It appears to be a bit of a quirk and I would not rely on this in case it gets changed in future versions.

Comment: See the excellent answer in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964926/is-an-enum-constant-specific-class-body-static-or-non-static) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can either declare the `currentUpperBound` method as `abstract` and implement it in your instances, or leave it implemented.

In both cases, you should declare it with a non-`private` access modifier.

The compiler error message here is quite confusing. 
It assumes `currentUpperBound` should be `static`, which would grant you access from the instances even if the method is declared as `private`.